# ORDERing within JOIN in MySQL - latest messsage per user

Tags: mysql, join

Got two versions of a query. Neither does quite what I need..

Trying to return all users, along with the time of the latest message sent *either* **to OR from** that user. An additional flag shows whether that last message was **from** the user in the current row (hence whether they're 'awaiting response').

Finally, the entire result set needs to be ordered to have those users 'awaiting response' first, and secondarily ordered by the time of the latest message.

Version 1:

```
SELECT `users`.*,
MAX(`messages`.`time_sent`) AS `_message_time_sent`,
(`messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) AS `_message_awaiting_response` 
FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `messages` 
ON (`messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` OR `messages`.`to_user_id` = `users`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `users`.`id` 
ORDER BY `_message_awaiting_response` DESC, `messages`.`time_sent` DESC
```

The problem with version 1: the '_message_sent_time' is correct (via MAX), but the '_message_awaiting_response' flag is always derived from whichever message appeared first in the join before the MAX() occurred, which may not be the most recent message.

Version 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.*,
`messages`.`time_sent` AS `_message_time_sent`,
(`messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) AS `_message_awaiting_response`
FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `messages`
ON (`messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` OR `messages`.`to_user_id` = `users`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `users`.`id` 
ORDER BY `_message_awaiting_response` DESC, `messages`.`time_sent` DESC
```

With version 2, the problem is largely the same - due to there being no MAX() aggregate function, the first message found in the join (not the most recent) is singled-out by DISTINCT.

Is there a simple way of making sure the latest message gets targeted here?

P.S. It needs to work in MySQL 4 ;)

Comment: Oops, my bad .. wanted to show users who've been waiting LONGEST for a response first, so 2nd order by should be `messages`.`time_sent` ASC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this should be:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT `users`.*,
        `messages`.`time_sent` AS `_message_time_sent`,
        (`messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) AS `_message_awaiting_response` 
 FROM `users` 
 LEFT JOIN `messages` 
        ON `messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` OR 
           `messages`.`to_user_id` = `users`.`id`
 ORDER BY `users`.`id`, `messages`.`time_sent` DESC
) V
GROUP BY V.`id` 
ORDER BY `_message_awaiting_response` DESC, `_message_time_sent` DESC
```

However, it should be stressed that although this probably *will* work, it cannot be *guaranteed* to work - unaggregated, ungrouped values included in a grouped select statement are normally those first in order, but MySQL documentation does not describe this behaviour as reliable.

An alternative that should always work (provided that a given user doesn't have multiple messages with the same timestamp) would be:

```
select u.*,
       m.`time_sent` AS `_message_time_sent`,
       (m.`user_id` = u.`id`) AS `_message_awaiting_response` 
from `users` u
left join (select `user_id`, max(`time_sent`) AS `last_sent`
           from (select `time_sent`, `user_id` from `messages` union all
                 select `time_sent`, `to_user_id` `user_id` from `messages`) v
           group by `user_id`) lm
       on u.`user_id` = lm.`user_id`
left join `messages` m
       ON m.`time_sent` = lm.`last_sent` and 
          lm.`user_id` in (m.`user_id`, m.`to_user_id`)
ORDER BY `_message_awaiting_response` DESC, `_message_time_sent` DESC
```

Comment: This looks right to me. Can you elaborate on why this might not work?

Comment: Great, looking good so far .. GROUP BY needed to be V.`id` however.. Thanks!

Comment: @BenLee it works because the subquery is doing the ordering correctly first, before the GROUP BY occurs..

Comment: @JonnyNott, I understand why it works. I asked why it *might not work* based on the disclaimer that Mark wrote at the bottom.

Comment: I did suspect that doing the ordering bit in a subquery would probably be the way forward, just couldn't get my head around it ;(

Comment: @JonnyNott: Thanks, answer amended accordingly.

Comment: @BenLee: I have updated my answer to explain that unaggregated, ungrouped values included in a grouped select statement are normally those first in order, but MySQL documentation does not describe this behaviour as reliable. This has been discussed elsewhere on SO - it seems as though this *normally* works, but should not be *relied on*.